How to construct covariance matrix on frequency domain
When we use time domain received signal to construct the interference and noise covariance matrix, sometimes the undesired clutter will also be included and affect the accuracy of the covariance matrix.
To solve it, I heard that we can perform 2D-FFT on our received multi-channel signal, and just choose the data matrix without clutter to construct the covariance matrix. (Clutter, like ground clutter will be basically at low doppler region)
I think it's a great idea, but I have some questions here:

Is this construction equal to the time domain expression? How can we prove it?
Such as, for power calculation, $P = \mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{w}$, where $\mathbf{w}$ is the weight and $\mathbf{R}=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{yy}^H\right]$ is the covariance matrix calculated on time domain, it looks quite intuitive to me, as we are just weighting, combining and averaging it on time domain ($\mathbf{y}$ is defined below).
If we perform FFT on $\mathbf{y}$, then for $\mathbf{R}^{\prime}=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{YY}^H\right]$, where $\mathbf{Y}$ is the FFT of $\mathbf{y}$, can we still calculate the output power as $P = \mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{R}^{\prime}\mathbf{w}$?
For a single element, FFT find the the frequency response of the signal, what does it mean if we perform FFT on different elements but same snapshot? We transform phase difference between elements to what?
Meanwhile, if we perform 2D-FFT, will the FFT on one dimension affect the FFT output of another dimension?

Array Model:
Suppose we have a $M\times N$ planar array with half wave length spacing, and the recieved signal can be expressed as
$$\mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{a_s x}(t) + \sum_i^{J}\mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{z}_i +\mathbf{n}(t)$$
where $\mathbf{a_s}\in \mathbb{C}^{MN\times 1} $ is the steering vector of desired signal $\mathbf{x}$,
$\mathbf{a_i}\in \mathbb{C}^{MN\times 1} $ is the steering vector of $i$th jammer,
$\mathbf{z}_i$ is the jamming signal of $i$th jammer,
and $\mathbf{n}$ is the additive white gaussian noise.

I believe that 1) can be reached through the linearity of the Fourier transform and the relation between the cross-correlation function ($\mathbf{R}$) and the cross-spectral density ($\mathbf{R}^{\prime}$). Regarding 2) I am not sure what you mean perform FFT inter-array element (I may just be missing the point here); would you care to clarify that a bit? Regarding the 2D FFT I am not sure what you mean exactly. The order you perform FFT doesn’t matter, but if you change something in the FFT of one dimension it will change the final result of the 2D FFT.

Sorry for the ambiguity here. What I mean is, when we perform FFT on the received time domain data matrix, for each row, we will get the spectrum of the signal on that antenna. Then, if we perform FFT on each column, which is the received signal on different antennas at the same snapshot, what we get from it?

Well, from the way you present it now, I guess that calculating the FFT over the snapshop you’d get something like the spatial Fourier Transform for that snapshot. I am not sure this will give you exactly the covariance matrix on the frequency domain. I believe the covariance matrix should be calculated per frequency in the frequency domain. This could be done by getting the expected value of the spectrums (average over time) and at each frequency bin you would calculate the product $\mathbf{Y} \left( \omega \right) \mathbf{Y} \left( \omega \right)^{H}$.

Really thanks, I am just wondering whether I should perform FFT both on column and row of the data matrix. Anyway, I think I can follow your hint and really write something down to see what happens there.

Do you have a reference, like a paper or something, for this idea?

@Baddioes, I assume the question was addressed to me. I don’t think I have some reference for the specific algorithm. I just thought it is quite intuitive, since getting the expectation of the Fourier transforms of the signals should be functionally equivalent togetting the Fourier transform of the expectation of the correlation functions due to linearity. Then, all you should do is calculate the auto and cross-spectral densities from these “expected” spectral densities. Please correct me if I'm wrong or you think there’s something I missed or misunderstood.

Okay, I just wasn't sure if you had a reference for the idea to see if the math was more explicitly worked out already and you were trying to understand it, or if this was an idea you had. I'll post an answer with what I'm thinking.

I think you have an interesting question, but it is a bit unclear. Can you edit it, providing more context up front? It sounds like you have a multi-channel array collecting time domain data on each channel, such that you have an LxMN array of data (where L is the number of time samples and MN is the number of spatial channels). I believe you also have interference from "ground clutter," but you only want to null other interference sources, not the "ground clutter?" Are you expecting other interference sources to appear in a different location in the frequency domain from the "ground clutter?"

@Gillespie Sorry for replying late. Yes, you are right, I want to achieve a pure covariance matrix with mainly interference and noise but not clutter, as clutter might deviate my null towards the interference. So I am expecting these components will appear at different locations on the 2D-FFT plot. Such as, ground clutter usually has trivial doppler information.

Let $\underline{y}$ be a signal with $\underline{Y}$ being it's DFT representation. We then have the relationship
\begin{equation}
\underline{Y} = \mathbf{F}\underline{y}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{F}$ is the unitary DFT matrix. Given that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{R} &= E\left[\underline{y}\underline{y}^{H}\right] \\
P &= \underline{w}^{H}\mathbf{R}\underline{w}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\underline{w}$ is the weighting vector, we wish to find an expression for
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{R}' &= E\left[\underline{Y}\underline{Y}^{H}\right] \\
P' &= \underline{v}^{H}\mathbf{R}'\underline{v}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
such that $P=P'$. Plugging in for $\underline{Y}$ gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{R}' &= E\left[\mathbf{F}\underline{y}\underline{y}^{H}\mathbf{F}^{H}\right] = \mathbf{F}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F}^{H} \\
P' &= \underline{v}^{H}\mathbf{F}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F}^{H}\underline{v}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Because of the unitary property of the DFT matrix, we can recognize that by letting $\underline{v}=\mathbf{F}\underline{w}$ we get
\begin{equation}
P' = \underline{v}^{H}\mathbf{F}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F}^{H}\underline{v} = \left(\mathbf{F}\underline{w}\right)^{H}\mathbf{F}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F}^{H}\left(\mathbf{F}\underline{w}\right) = \underline{w}^{H}\mathbf{F}^{H}\mathbf{F}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F}^{H}\mathbf{F}\underline{w} = \underline{w}^{H}\mathbf{R}\underline{w}.
\end{equation}
So, in order to get equivalence you have to take the Fourier transform of the weights, and the DFT matrix has to have a unitary scaling.
As for whether or not a good approximation of the covariance matrix can be achieved through this method or not, I'm not sure an exact answer can be reached, and it might be case dependent. For noise, you can likely get a good estimate assuming successive draws from the noise distribution are statistically uncorrelated. Since the DFT is an orthogonal transform, statistically uncorrelated input data will remain statistically uncorrelated at the output. However, for correlated input data, such as jammers, the data will most likely not be uncorrelated in the DFT representation. Therefore, the jammer response in the DFT may be at least partially contained in the low doppler region where the clutter resides, and excluding this information could give a poor estimate of the interference portion of your covariance matrix. You can always make the assumption that it isn't, but who knows. This is starting to get into the idea of space-time adaptive processing (STAP). The idea is that the clutter will be localized in doppler, whereas your jammers are localized in angle, and your targets are localized in doppler-angle.
This also starts to get at your second question. If you perform an FFT across array elements at a single snapshot, this will give you a basic estimate of the direction-of-arrival (DOA) of the incoming signal since a constant, progressive phase shift across your elements corresponds to a constant spatial frequency (see beam pattern are fourier transform of the beam weight, is it true?). This is only true under a narrowband, plane-wave assumption, so if your signal isn't narrow band or in the far-field, this won't hold. Typically we assume it's in the far field, but you may need to do subband processing if it's not a narrowband signal. As for whether or not an FFT on one dimension will affect the FFT on the second dimension, it won't. A 2D-FFT can be performed by two 1D-FFTs.
A more general question I have is why are you trying to exclude the clutter in your covariance matrix estimate? The only reason I can think of is if you are trying to observe clutter characteristics, as in SAR for example. Other than that, clutter is typically a nuisance, so I'm not understanding why you wouldn't want to include it in your interference-plus-noise covariance matrix.
One last thing, the covariance matrix $\mathbf{R}$ is not the same as the correlation/covariance function. The covariance matrix can be constructed from the covariance function and vice versa, but $\mathbf{R}'$ is not a spectral density function, it is a type of covariance matrix. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't confusion on that.

Setup
I'll take a stab at this from another angle (pun intended). I don't fully understand your scenario, but I'm assuming your case satisfies the narrow-band assumption (bandwidth << carrier frequency). If that's not the case, then you have to do things a bit differently. Let your data be $L\times N$, where $L$ is the number of time samples and $N$ is the number of spatial channels . For now, we'll assume you have a uniform linear array (spaced $d = \lambda/2$), and deal with the 2D array case later.
Question 1
In general, you can treat the different dimensions of your data independently. If you take an FFT in the time dimension, the phase relationships between the spatial channels will be unchanged (as long as you do the same thing to every channel). Therefore, you can beamform in the spatial dimension with the same exact steering vector you would have used before the temporal FFT.
If instead you take an FFT in the spatial dimension (or a 2D FFT in time and space), you now have to use a different weight vector. Consider that before the spatial FFT, you would beamform using $w^H y$. The FFT is a linear transformation, so if you take the FFT of $y$ to obtain $Y$ first, you need to perform the same operation on $w$ to get the equivalent result in the spatial frequency domain (see also Baddioes' excellent answer):
$$ FFT(w^H y) = FFT(w)^H FFT(y) = W^H Y $$
$$ IFFT(W^H Y) = w^H y $$
So you can still "beamform" in the spatial frequency domain, but you have to take the FFT of your weight vector $w$ before using it. Once you've transformed everything (weight vectors and data) to the spatial frequency domain, everything can be done the exact same way as in the channel domain, including covariance formation and adaptive beamforming.
Question 2
When you take the FFT across spatial channels, you transform from channel space to angle space, effectively beamforming to a specific set of angles.
To see this, consider that for a ULA the steering vector is $v(\theta) = e^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} nd \sin\theta}$, $n = 0:N-1$. Then, the beamforming operation looks like:
$$ v(\theta)^Hy = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} nd\sin(\theta)} y[n] $$
Compare this with the K-length DFT:
$$ Y[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-2\pi\frac{k}{K} n} y[n] , k = 0:K-1 $$
Thus, to get these two equations to be equivalent, we need $\frac{d}{\lambda} \sin(\theta) = \frac{k}{K}$. Solving this for $\theta$, we see that taking the FFT in the spatial dimension effectively beamforms for a set of non-uniformly spaced angles (they are uniformly spaced in sine space):
$$ \theta_k = \sin^{-1}(\frac{\lambda k}{d K}) , k = 0:K-1 $$
Extending to a 2D array
You indicate that you actually have an $M \times N$ planar array, such that your steering vectors and weight vectors are technically 2D, but for convenience vectorized to $MN \times 1$. In this case, if you take the FFT of the vectorized $w$, you are no longer transforming to an intelligible angle space, because you don't have a ULA anymore, and the horizontal and vertical dimensions are mixed together in $w$. This doesn't change the answer to Question 1 (all the same math holds no matter what the FFT of $w$ physically represents), but it does change the answer to Question 2.
If you want the spatial FFT of the beamformer/weight vector to make sense in terms of angle space, you need to reshape it back into an $M \times N$ weight matrix, then take the FFT in the $M$ and $N$ dimensions (a 2D spatial FFT, not to be confused with the 2D temporal-spatial FFT!). You could then re-vectorize this $W$ for convenient future calculations.
Will your idea work?
The premise of your question seems to be that you believe you can separate the "ground clutter" returns from other interference sources by taking an FFT in the time domain. I don't know if that is true or not without knowing more about your scenario, but assuming it is, you could filter out the ground clutter (perhaps with a high pass filter if the ground clutter is all at low frequencies) in the time dimension before computing the covariance matrix.
Simply taking the high frequency bins and using them to compute the covariance may work well enough, but that is like using a very poor high-pass filter and you will have leakage effects, so YMMV.
